# Can I fly under a solar eclipse to lengthen its effect?

Tags: aircraft-performance

There is going to be a solar eclipse in 2017 and I thought it would be cool to fly along its path to make it longer than the approximately two and a half minutes you would see on the ground.

Is this a bad idea?

Should I go to fast or slow for the solar eclipse?

I think it would be fun to fly during the solar eclipse, even if I can't keep pace with it.

Comment: There is no regulation (in the US) preventing you from flying "under" a solar eclipse. Night flying regulations do not apply in this case so you don't need to be night current. You will not be keeping pace with it though, you may extend it by a few seconds, but not significantly.

Comment: Or perhaps you could persuade an airline to participate to the event: [Alaska Airlines adjusts flight plan to delight astronomers](https://blog.alaskaair.com/alaska-airlines/news/eclipse-flight/). At least you will be over the clouds. Be sure to have a seat on the good side though :-)

Comment: Hopefully you would be concentrating on flying the airplane rather than looking at the solar eclipse.

Comment: https://wiralfeed.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/sun-eater1.jpg

Comment: This article might interest you : ["Flight to Totality: How I Chased the Total Solar Eclipse of 2015 on a Jet"](http://www.space.com/28886-total-solar-eclipse-2015-airplane-view.html)

Comment: [Very related.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22083/how-were-astronomical-observations-performed-from-concorde)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The speed at which the shadow of the Moon crosses the Earth varies according to time of day and latitude. However, 1500mph is a good starting point.

The only supersonic commercial aircraft to enter service was Concorde, top speed around 1350mph. And, of course, Concorde is now out of service.

Flying something subsonic along the path of totality will give a longer view, but most airliners top out at around 600mph.

You've really no chance of keeping up with it. You're probably better off finding a spot with a good view and enjoying your 2.5 minutes!

Nasa have a range of materials dedicated to this. If you fancy a little mental gymnastics  take a look at https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/challenge-5-%E2%80%93-estimating-speed-lunar-shadow. In particular, download the PDF worksheet and do the maths!

Comment: Too bad the SR-71 is retired...

Comment: Are there any regulations of flying under a solar elcipse?

Comment: @William you could edit that into your question or ask a separate question asking about regulations of flying during an eclipse.

Comment: @William See [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13377/is-an-eclipse-considered-night-for-regulatory-purposes).

Comment: @Steve Thank you!  I think I would have found it if had been labeled solar eclipse and not eclipse.  I don't want this to be a duplicate so I have edited  the question title to be slightly more specific.

Comment: According to [this site](http://eclipse2017.org/blog/2016/11/27/how-fast-is-the-shadow-moving-across-the-us-during-the-eclipse/) the slowest section of the 2017 eclipse will be 1462 mph or 1270 kts. SR-71 could achieve 1982kn ground speed. It could keep up.

Comment: @mins Actually at 85,000 ft the umbra would be slightly larger, thus easier to track

Comment: @mins Because the light source (sun) is larger than the object casting the shadow (moon). The shadow is a cone. But you, as an astrophysicist should know this! (see comments on [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37690/8730)

Comment: @mins but I doubt 85,000 feet would make much of a difference considering the source is 239,000 miles away

Comment: @mins I sent you a diagram on chat, but it didn't tag u. Feel free to ignore it, though.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. The shadow of the moon goes too fast to keep up with that, but there are other reasons to do it. Firstly, when you fly over the clouds, you can be sure they don't obstruct your view. Second reason is that sometimes solar eclipse, or the best part of it, only appear over an ocean.

Here is an article from last year. Couple of interesting quotes from it:

"Taking to the skies during the sun being eclipsed out of view behind the moon, is not a new concept. In fact in 1887, Dmitri Mendeleev, the Russian inventor, was so keen to see the eclipse without cloud obstruction that he rode in a hot air balloon when it took place."

"In the past private operators have capitalised on the event by offering special eclipse flights."

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3475224/Out-world-best-commercial-flights-witnessing-total-solar-eclipse.html